# CSS : div position overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a screenshot of the page

[image]

I want to move "img" div to the right of "regionbutton" div

then I set regionbutton div and img div on css to be **float:left**

and "chartwithoverlay" div with **clear:both**

but the result seems like everydiv overlap each other like this [see this link](http://sagisepr.com/CLEANMAPS/test1menu.html)

In addition,I didn't set anything for "colormap" div (inside chartwithoverlay)which contain maps chart
but it has a div inside from google chart like this

[image]

THis is the code

```css
div{

 font-family: Roboto;
}
#regionbutton{
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 
 }
#img{
 width:700px;
 float:right;
}
}
#chartwithoverlay1{
 clear:both;
 position: relative;
}
#overlay1{
    width: 400px;
       height: 50px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#636466;
       position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
       top: 550px;   /* chartArea top */
       left: 10px /* chartArea left */
 }
 
#chartwithoverlay2{
  clear:both;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay2{
    width: 400px;
       height: 50px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#636466;
       position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
       top: 550px;   /* chartArea top */
       left: 10px /* chartArea left */
 }
 
#chartwithoverlay3{
 clear:both;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay3{
    width: 400px;
       height: 50px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#636466;
       position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
       top: 550px;   /* chartArea top */
       left: 10px /* chartArea left */
 }
```

```html
<div id="regionbutton">
 <div id="radio1"><input type="radio" name="region" id="all" value="all" /><label for="all">All</label></div>
 <div id="radio2"><input type="radio" name="region" id="africa" value="002" /><label for="africa">Africa</label></div>
 <div id="radio3"><input type="radio" name="region" id="americas" value="019" /><label for="americas">Americas</label></div>
 <div id="radio4"><input type="radio" name="region" id="europe" value="150" /><label for="europe">Europe</label></div>
 <div id="radio5"><input type="radio" name="region" id="asia" value="142" /><label for="asia">Asia</label></div>
</div>

<div id="img">
    <img src="legend.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="chartwithoverlay1">
     <div id="overlay1">WEEE</div>
  <div id='colormap1'> </div>
    </div>
 
 <div id="chartwithoverlay2">
     <div id="overlay2">Batteries</div>
  <div id='colormap2'> </div>
    </div>
 
 <div id="chartwithoverlay3">
     <div id="overlay3">Packaging</div>
  <div id='colormap3'> </div>
    </div>
```

So what is the right way to set position for each div?

Comment: Divs by definition are block elements that take up 100% width by default.  try changing their `display` property to `inline-block`.

Comment: @sn3ll you made my day! thanks.